# Show labels in legend in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer, legend

Is there a way to report a point layer's labels from the map to the legend in the Print-Composer ?

I have a quite dense point layer for which I need to display names. They wont fit on the map, so I though I might just assign them numbers, and display their names alongside the numbers in the legend.

Is there a way to achieve this in QGIS (currently using 2.18.10) ?

Comment: You can add the table of points Instead of legend

Comment: What do you mean by "table of points" ? I want to show the list of points with their ids and names in the Composer. I edited my question to clarify that I meant "in the print composer".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this.You can add table of layer contents.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did any of this help you??

Comment: Yes, that looks very promising, thanks ! I have not found a way to change the columns width though. I have set the table text to be truncated if too large, but the table frame always takes the entire page's width. Can this be changed ? In a regular legend object, I can set the number of columns so that the content can flow on a single page, and that is way I am trying to replicate here.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that not every point has a different label so you could  build classes of points something like in the first image: 
[image]
You also can use the same color for every class of cause. 
From here you simply change the Legend entry like this:
[image]

Enable the labeling with the same column. In the print composer you then simply add the layer to the legend and thus will get the resulting image: 
[image]

**Side note:**
Be aware that cartographic wise, you shouldn't use more than 10 - 15 points + labels per square centimeter because else you will have too much obscured. For a general look see this nice overview [from e-cartouche.ch](http://www.e-cartouche.ch/content_reg/cartouche/cartdesign/en/html/index.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, every point has a different label. This layer is a set of named points, and I'd like to have only the IDs on the map and the corresponding names in the legend.